# AWS S3 Bucket File - Rename object that has backslash into folder and file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have some old uploaded S3 objects that were supposed to be in a subfolder/filename format, but mistakenly used a backslash which made the subfolder part of the actual object's filename.

Using the aws cli, how will I be able to recursively run through all my objects that have a backslash (`folder\file`), make a new subfolder with the foldername, and place the object with the correct filename inside (`folder/file`)?

From this

```
bucket
    folder1\file1
    folder1\file2
    folder1\file3
```

To this

```
bucket
    folder1
        file1
        file2
        file3
```

Answer (score 2):

S3 does not have "folders", it only has "keys".
You need to list all the objects and then **copy** the object to a key with proper / in it, e.g. `folder1/file1`, then you can **delete** the old file. There is no move operation in S3. And you will not need to create a folder. "Folders" only exist within the aws web console since they are needed for human interaction.

Comment: So the "folders" I see in the web console are effectively just keys that are still part of the entire object's path? So how will I be able to do what I want above using aws cli?

Comment: @slimjourney your first need to `list`, then filter the list according to your logic and then `copy` and then `delete`.